# How to configure nginx to redirect all request from domain aliases to main domain?

Tags: nginx, web-server, redirect, 301-redirect

I do have an nginx server which responds to several domains and I do want to redirect all request to the main domain.

Example: website responding for `xxx xxx.example.com yyy.example.com $hostname` for both `http` and `https`.

I want to configure the server in such  way that all requests to the other domain names will be redirected to `xxx.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks something along these lines should work:

```
set $primary_domain "xxx.example.com";
if ($host != $primary_domain) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$primary_domain permanent;
}
```

Comment: This is the worst way to solve the problem.
http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name and
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: Marking down for the reasons already stated by VBart. In my opinion this should not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

Most efficient and clean way to do this is to configure two separate server{} blocks - one to do redirects, and another one (with canonical name) to actually handle requests.

Example configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name xxx yyy.example.com $hostname;

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...

    return 302 $scheme://xxx.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name xxx.example.com;

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...

    ...
}
```

Documentation:

- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/return

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant on Brenton Alker's anser, using the [`$server_name` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name) to reuse the value of the `server_name` directive.

```
    server_name primary.tld secondary.tld;
    if ($host != $server_name) {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://$server_name permanent;
    }
```

Or, to keep any query parameters:

```
    server_name primary.tld secondary.tld;
    if ($host != $server_name) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) $scheme://$server_name/$1 permanent;
    }
```

Here, [`$server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name) refers to primary server name, which is the first name in the `server_name` directive, while [`$host`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) refers to the hostname given in the HTTP request.

Note that the `if` statement in nginx configuration does not always do what you would expect and its use is discouraged by some. See also https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/